# Microservice and processing received messages sequentially

Tags: c#, .net-core, microservices, message-queue, hangfire

I have a microservice system with N instance and my business is based on OrderId unique value. For each OrderId, I get 4 messages, the first message take a long time for processing and during processing the first message, I get the second message and other messages. I want to force the system to process them sequentially. What is your idea about this scenario?

My idea for this scenario contains share memory techniques (cache server)  and hangfire (using BackgroundJob.ContinueWith), but I'm searching for best practice.

Comment: https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/Resequencer.html

Comment: Pause the listener until the 1st msg is complete processing and then pick up the other 3.

Comment: @RandomUs1r, I get 1000 message (250 OrderId) per second, I can't pause listener just for an OrderId.

Comment: @Nigje seems like something worth mentioning in the body of the question.  Have you look into Idempotent operations > https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/idempotent-operation-in-distributed-system/ .  Your other messages would check and wait for the 1st one to finish via as you propose a cache for example. The other idea is to use threading, which seems a lot like your hangfire idea. And one idea you haven't thought of might be to use reactive extensions (RX).

Answer (score 0):

In a standard messaging solution such as Kafka, you can use the orderId as a partition key. This will ensure that all messages of the same orderId will always end up in the same partition in the order they are produced. Different orders will go to different partitions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. My bus is based on RabbitMq. I'm searching for a third party for handling this problem.